# Modifying elements in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I currently have an excel table that I pulled from online. This table consists of approximately 150 sub tables, each with about 10-20 entries themselves. (This is the [website](http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/search.php) in question). In each sub table (so, for example, subject 1) I need to update the field of each table value. So, instead of the value of each of trials 1-14 being "tvd", I would like it to be the file name, so 01_01.tvd. However, for the second trial, this value becomes 01_02.tvd, and so on, until we reach subject2, whose files are named 02_01.tvd. Is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: OPTION 1: This sounds like it could be easily done using a short piece of VBA  code.  Do you have any programming experience?      Also you say you have an "excel table" and "150 sub tables",  are these on the same sheet in excel or are the sub tables in separate sheets?   It wouldn't matter significantly to the code.       OPTION 2: The alternative is to use a formula which, after calculation, is replaced by itself using "paste values".   No code so less experience required.